# Unable to retrive data stored under data attribute

Tags: jquery

I am reading a inner array named **Tag_Details** ,
 if its length is greater than  3 , i am appending dots and storing data under a data attribute associated with tagid to retrieve it later purpose

In case length is greater than 3 , i am appending data as shown below

This is my code

```
displayallVideos(json)

  function displayallVideos(response)
  {
          var videolisthtml = '';
          total_records = response.total_count;
           var span = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < response.Video_details.length; i++)
          {
                  var video_id = response.Video_details[i].video_id;
                  var video_name = response.Video_details[i].video_name;
                  var video_file = response.Video_details[i].video_file;
                  var how_to_video = response.Video_details[i].how_to_video;
                  var video_created_date = response.Video_details[i].video_created_date
                  videolisthtml += '<tr class="portlettr"  id="tagnames'+video_id+'" data-stuff="" data-id="' + video_id + '">\
                            <td>' + video_name + '</td>\n\
                            <td>'+ response.Video_details[i].video_file.split('/').pop() + '</td>\n'
                  var vd = response.Video_details[i].Tag_Details;
                  videolisthtml += '<td>\n';
                  for (var j = 0; j < vd.length; j++)
                  {
                          var tag_name = vd[j].tag_name;
                            span = '<span class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-circle"></span> ';
                          if (j < 3)
                          {
                                  videolisthtml += span.split("</span>").join(tag_name + "</span>");
                          }
                          else
                          {
                               span = '<span class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-circle btnredcolor"></span> ';
                                  var valuefromutility = getcommasperatedvalue(vd);
                                  videolisthtml += span.split("</span>").join('...' + "</span>");
                                     $("#tagnames" + video_id).data('stuff', valuefromutility).attr('data-stuff', JSON.stringify(valuefromutility));
                                  break;
                          }
                  }
                  videolisthtml += '</td>\n';
                  videolisthtml += '<td>' + video_created_date + '</td>\n\
                            </tr>';
          }
          $("#videolisttable tbody").html(videolisthtml);
  }

  function getcommasperatedvalue(arr)
  {
          var arrayafter3elemnts = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
          {
                  if (i > 2)
                  {
                          if (i === arr.length - 1)
                          {
                                  arrayafter3elemnts += arr[i].tag_name;
                          }
                          else
                          {
                                  arrayafter3elemnts += arr[i].tag_name + ',';
                          }
                  }
          }
          return arrayafter3elemnts;
  }


  $(document).on('click', '.btnredcolor', function(event)
{
          var video_id = $(this).closest('.portlettr').data("id");
        var vendoritemsdata = $("#tagnames" + video_id).data('stuff');
        alert(vendoritemsdata);
});
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/402/

Could you please tell me how to resolve this

Comment: you need some value in that data attribute first

Comment: thanks , but i dont want hardcoded values , i am trying to set them dynamically

Comment: Are you sure your code passes place where you set data attribute? Also `.attr('data-stuff', JSON.stringify())` is not needed

Comment: you don't have the elements on the page man when you add the attributes

Comment: ok this seeems very good point , now i am getting it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not doing anything special with your data attribute (IE using it for json strings etc) you may as well call it using attr('data-stuff') which should work.

the data('stuff') call tries to parse the string but can also caches the value and so won't re-check it when called upon again.

Though, on top of that - your elements werent actually on the page at the time of using the attribute, they were just a string of html. I've added each element to an array which is then iterated over to add them once they are on the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/412/

```
valuesfromutility["#tagnames" + video_id] = valuefromutility;
```

then

```
      if ($(valuesfromutility).length) {
          $.each(valuesfromutility, function(element, value){
              $(element).attr('data-stuff', value);
          });
      }
```

Comment: tried as you mentioned but still the value is empty http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/404/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/406/ Try again, you did "attr('stuff')" needs to be "attr('data-stuff')"

Comment: thanks Craig , but still from your fiddle also  the value is empty know .

Comment: Sorry, just looked again, you didnt actually have any data in the attribute.

Comment: test is harcoded , trying to set it dynamially  $("#tagnames" + video_id).attr('data-stuff', valuefromutility).attr('data-stuff', JSON.stringify(valuefromutility));

Comment: Sorry I see that, one minute ill look again

Comment: Just saw that you havent yet added the element to the page, it is just a string of html. 

I'm working on a solution, currently http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/410/ but not yet complete

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/411/

There you go, I add them as an array and set them once theyre on the page

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the solution, please accept if you're happy :)

Comment: thanks once again , its working , and ur profile pic is too good .